# Does using non-carthage compatible framework with Carthage work?

Tags: ios, dependency-management, carthage

Im new to using Carthage as my dependency-manager, instead of using Cocoapods. 
And I'm just wondering if it is possible in any way to use the GoogleMaps SDK for iOS without having to fall back to Cocoapods again?